# Show sweet alert on load if file not an image

Tags: javascript, html

can anybody help me? 
i tried several times but failed. 
how can I show a sweet alert on file select if the input file is not an image?

```
<input type ="file" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is working demo: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/d7vpbet6/6/

You can use jQuery to see if the selected file is image type or not.

**jQuery**

```
function uploadImage(_this) {
  var file = _this.files[0];
  var fileType = file["type"];
  var validImageTypes = ["image/gif", "image/jpeg", "image/png"];
  if ($.inArray(fileType, validImageTypes) < 0) {
       alert('Please select an image! Fill is not an image')
       _this.form.reset()
  } else {
    alert('All good')
     //do something
  }
}
```

If you do not want to use jQuery. You can do this via Javascript as well.

**JavaScript**

```
function uploadImage(_this) {
  const file = _this.files[0];
  const  fileType = file['type'];
  const validImageTypes = ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
  if (!validImageTypes.includes(fileType)) {
     alert('Please select an image! Fill is not an image')
     document.getElementById("uploading_images").reset();
  } else {
    alert('All good')
  }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="uploading_images">
 <input type="file" id="upload_image" onChange="uploadImage(this)" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps.